# Android NDK Call Java Function

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am not sure if this is possible but I am developing a native Android program, a Linux executable that calls the Android API using the NDK.

This code works normally and I see the output of Hello world when I run it in shell.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>

using namespace std;

static JavaVM *g_VM;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!";

    return 0;
}
```

This code does not even print the "Hello world"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jni.h>

using namespace std;

static JavaVM *g_VM;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!";

    JNIEnv *env;
    env->GetJavaVM(&g_VM);

    return 0;
}
```

This is very confusing to me.

Comment: You obviously cannot invoke `GetJavaVM` on a `JNIEnv*` that you haven't initialized.

Comment: https://calebfenton.github.io/2017/04/05/creating_java_vm_from_android_native_code/ may be relevant.

Comment: @Michael That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

well, this is right, But if you want to study more then go on the developer site and check out the full docs[Link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/). Java code is run by Dalvik VM on Android. Dalvik VM is specially designed for systems with constrained hardware resources (memory space, processor speed, and so on). So if you USE NDK for system controlling its a good approach otherwise you should use the java instead.

Comment: All of the examples on the Internet develop just a portion of the code in C++ and use Java to call the C++ functions. I'd like to make it all in C++ and run it by shell.

Comment: Why? If it's just some command-line utility rather than an app, why do you care about interfacing with Java?

Comment: @DanAlbert I'm developing an anti-theft app that will be installed on devices using root. Via this I would be able to put it on startup via a non Android API method, like using InitV and do stuff without being visible. Cerberus is an example of a good anti-theft app but not perfect, I've heard situations where a thief would just uninstall it or disabled it in case it was installed in /system/app and it was useless...